# How to wrap a variable and push the html into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push this html into an array on a click

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V9GsS-aMVNs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
     </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">10:35</span></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var urls = [];
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  var $myVideo = $(this).parent().parent().wrap('<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"/>');
  var $myVideoWrapped = $($myVideo.html());
  console.log($myVideoWrapped.html());
  urls.push($myVideoWrapped.html());
  $('#usp-custom-5').text(urls.join(' '));
});
```

That gives me in console:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3BXL9opyOdo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

While I would to get the whole html as per above

Comment: try `console.log($myVideo.prop('outerHTML'))`

Comment: You could also create your div and append the closest thumbnail to it: `$('<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"/>').append($(this).closest('.thumbnail').clone())`. As others have said, you are getting the `innerHTML`, which does not include the selected element (also, nice name :P)

Comment: @RobM. haha, thanks man! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var urls = [];
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  var $myVideo = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('outerHTML');
  //console.log($myVideo);
  urls.push($myVideo);
  console.log(urls[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V9GsS-aMVNs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
     </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">10:35</span></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually when we click on this, we are not justing placing the html into the textarea but we are also wrapping the selected div within another div, breaking the layout

Comment: this is how i resolved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028721/how-to-add-html-content-of-selected-div-into-a-textarea/43028987#43028987

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.