# How to add html content of selected div into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following works fine, but when I add the html into the textarea, I am also wrapping the div within another div, breaking the layout.

```js
var urls = [];
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  var $myVideo = $(this).parent().parent().wrap('<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"/>');
  var $myVideoWrapped = $($myVideo.parent().parent());
  console.log($myVideoWrapped.html());
  urls.push($myVideoWrapped.html());
  $('#usp-custom-5').text(urls.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V9GsS-aMVNs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
     </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">10:35</span></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to place the whole html into the text area when pressing the button without to change the layout tho, basically placing this into the textarea:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V9GsS-aMVNs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
     </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">10:35</span></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: instead of using textarea you can use div and enable contenteditable property to true...

Comment: @RohitS true, but i do need it to be a textarea

Comment: ok so you simply want the the  parent div <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
html in textare??

Comment: @RohitS I would like when I press the button to place the whole html as stated above, but I don't want to change the html in the layout, if you try the snippet here, it does add the correct html into the textarea but it also changes for some reasons the layout html by wrapping another div around it

Comment: if i understood you are getting extra div attached to your html content...and if it is then its because of wrap() function..

Comment: yes but what i don't understand is why it is applied if that is defined as a variable

Comment: @RohitS anyway I have resolved it myself, check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I resolved it by using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and `outerHTML`

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
   var $imageSelected = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('outerHTML');
   $('#usp-custom-5').val(function(_, currentValue) {
      return currentValue + $imageSelected
    });
 });
```

Comment: ok..you needed the parent div along with its content....so outerHTML should solve exactly the problem.. :D 
also just a comment rather than using parent().parent().... so on simply consider adding class to div and get its content :D